EF Core ObservableColection CollectionChanged via HasConversion
I want to notify parent ReportModel when Technicians CollectionChanged. It works when creationg new ReportModel, but when I'm starting editing ReportModel from DB, ObservableCollection is created via HasConversion extension and CollectionChanged isn't fired anymore.
Any doubts how to achieve it?
public class ReportModel : ModelBase, IModel
{
private ObservableCollection<ReportPerson> technicians = new();
    
 public ReportModel()
 {
     Technicians.CollectionChanged += Technicians_CollectionChanged;
 }

 private void Technicians_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.NewItems != null)
     {
         foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
         {
             if (item is INotifyPropertyChanged notifyPropertyChanged)
                 notifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged += TechNotifyPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged;
         }
     }

     if (e.OldItems != null)
     {
         foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
         {
             if (item is INotifyPropertyChanged notifyPropertyChanged)
                 notifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged -= TechNotifyPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged;
         }
     }
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Technicians));
 }

 private void TechNotifyPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Technicians));


 [Column(name: "technicians", Order = 50)]
 public ObservableCollection<ReportPerson> Technicians
 {
     get => technicians;
     set
     {
         if (technicians != value)
         {
             if (technicians != null)
             {
                 technicians.CollectionChanged -= Technicians_CollectionChanged;
                 foreach (var tech in technicians)
                 {
                     if (tech is INotifyPropertyChanged notifyPropertyChanged)
                     {
                         notifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged -= TechNotifyPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged;
                     }
                 }
             }
             technicians = value;
             if (technicians != null)
             {
                 technicians.CollectionChanged += Technicians_CollectionChanged;
                 foreach (var tech in technicians)
                 {
                     if (tech is INotifyPropertyChanged notifyPropertyChanged)
                     {
                         notifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged += TechNotifyPropertyChanged_PropertyChanged;
                     }
                 }
             }
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Technicians));
         }
     }
 }
}


 modelBuilder.Entity<ReportModel>().Property(c => c.Technicians).HasConversion(
 v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
 v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObservableCollection<ReportPerson>>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null));



temporary I've created helper method on ReportModel class RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(propertyName)); and I call it manually when playing with ObservableColeection, but I'm sure that there's better solution

Use DTO or view model classes. Don't mix data access and UI concerns.
